# How to access https://localhost from other devices

Tags: reverse-proxy, forwarding

I have a server program written on ASP.NET that I would like to access from other devices on the same network. What do I need to do in order to achieve this? Is there a program that handles this type scenario? It must be https, not http.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're accessing it within the same network you should be able to use https://hostname:portnumber.

Unless the application itself has SSL support, one option would be to simply use Nginx as a reverse proxy and use it to apply the cert. You can use a location block to specify where traffic caught by nginx should be pointed (e.g. nginx is configured to listen on port 443, you reverse proxy it to localhost:9010 where the asp.net app is listening on 9010) and the simple SSL parameters to configure it to apply a certificate/private key.